# Check for specific value in specific position in hive

Tags: string, hive, substring, hiveql

In Hive, trying to build a logic around the following criteria check, but not able to come up with a solution for it.

criteria is if the first position of the string begins with 9 and has either 7 or 8 in the 4th position then to expose only the last four digits, else return all the 9 digits. How to accomplish the solution?

```
Input       Output 
---------------------
912345678   912345678
912756431   6431
912854321   4321
123456789   123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `substr` function:

```
select case when substr(Input,1,1)=9 and substr(Input,4,1) in (7,8) then substr(Input,-4) else Input end as Output
  from ...
```

Using `rlike`:

```
select case when Input rlike '^9\\d{2}[78]' then substr(Input,-4) else Input end as Output
```